# BAD_ACCESS when dismissing ViewController IOS on ios6 but not on ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have the following problem.

When dismissing the ViewController, the application crashes. However, I am following the same procedure that I use to open other View Controllers in my app. I just cannot see what is different in here and where to look.

I am using storyboard and I open the application like this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NotificationScreen *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationScreen"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and I am returning back like this:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The weird thing also is that in ios7, it does not crash, but crashes only on IOS6.

Where should I look?

The error that i get is EXC_BAD_ACCESS with no more information, just a `(lldb)` is printed.

Comment: Enable NSZombies (Edit your scheme, select the debug action, and check the box titled "Enable Zombie Objects"). This will give you some more useful information when the crash happens, most likely a "selector sent to deallocated object" error. The message should tell you the selector being called and which class it was sent to, hopefully helping you to track down the crash.

Comment: Also add exception breakpoints, maybe it will stop at the line that cause the crash.

Comment: Also remove the `presentingViewController`, just call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`